# why isn't this ember computed property firing for @each?

Tags: ember.js

i'm trying to use a computed property that observes a change on a particular attribute of every element in an array.  here's the fiddle.  click the change button, and the computed property does not fire.  why?

here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/inconduit/PkT8x/145/

and here's the relevant code

```
App.color1 = Ember.Object.create({ color : "red"});

// a contrived object that holds an array of color objects
App.colorsHolder = Ember.Object.create({
    colors : Ember.A([App.color1]),
});

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    colorsHolder : App.colorsHolder,

    // this should fire when you click the change button, but it does not
    colorsContainBlue : function() {
        console.log("fired colorsContainBlue");
        this.colorsHolder.colors.forEach(function(colorObj) {
            if(colorObj.get('color') == 'blue')
                return true;
        });
        return false;
    }.property('colorsHolder.@each.color'),                                  

    // this is a function called by an action in the template
    changeToBlue: function() {
        App.color1.set('color','blue');
        console.log("changed the color to: " + App.color1.get('color'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fiddle is a working example based on the one you provided.

http://jsfiddle.net/skane/PkT8x/147/

```
colorsContainBlue : function() {
    console.log("fired colorsContainBlue");
    if (this.colorsHolder.filterProperty('color', 'blue').length !== 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}.property('colorsHolder.@each.color'),                                  

changeToBlue: function() {
    this.get('colorsHolder').objectAt(0).set('color','blue');
}
```

I have changed numerous things in your example including:

1. changeToBlue now changes a property in the ApplicationController's colorHolder object (important)
2. computed property now observes the colorsHolder objects and specifically observes their 'color' prop
3. I have used filterProperty to determine if any object has a color value === 'blue'